# org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException. How to fix it?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

In my model are 3 entities(in real more than 3, but 3 is actually at  this situation)

1. Candidate
2. Vacancy
3. Event

They all have relation many to many(Candidate can have may Vacancies and many Events,  Vacancy ...candidates and... events.....).

If I update Candidate - good result.
if I update Vacancy - good result
BUT if I update Event I have `org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException`

It shows when I change collection of vacancy in Event. If I comment  place, where I change vacancies of event I have no problem(place `ONE` in my code)
Go to code:
Model mapping:

Vacancy:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vacancy")
@XmlRootElement(name="vacancy")
public class Vacancy {

    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private Date date;

    private User author;

    @XmlTransient
    private Set<Candidate> candidates = new HashSet<Candidate>();
    private Set<VacancyStatus> statusList = new HashSet<VacancyStatus>();
    private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<Skill>();
    private Set<Note> comments = new HashSet<Note>();
    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>();

    public Vacancy() {
        super();
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "vacancies", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public void setEvents(Set<Event> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }




    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }



    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "vacancies", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Candidate> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }

    public void setCandidates(Set<Candidate> candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj!= null && ((Vacancy)obj).getId() == id ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Integer id = getId();
        return id != null ? id.intValue() : super.hashCode();
    }
    ...
}
```

Candidate:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "candidate")
@XmlRootElement(name = "candidate")
public class Candidate extends Person {

    @Size(min=3,max=12)
    @Pattern(regexp="[0-9]*",message="phone format must be without + and - (for example: 89123353456)")
    private String phone;

    @Past
    private Date date;

    private User author;

    @Size(min=4, max=100)
    @URL()
    private String resumeUrl;

    private List<CandidateStatus> statusList = new LinkedList<CandidateStatus>();

    private Set<Vacancy> vacancies= new HashSet<Vacancy>();

    private Set<Skill> skills = new HashSet<Skill>();

    private List<Note> comments = new LinkedList<Note>();

    private Set<Event> events = new HashSet<Event>();

    public Candidate() {
        super();
    }

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "candidates", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    public Set<Event> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public void setEvents(Set<Event> events) {
        this.events = events;
    }


    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "candidate_vacancy", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "candidate_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vacancy_id"))
    @XmlTransient
    public Set<Vacancy> getVacancies() {
        return vacancies;
    }

    public void setVacancies(Set<Vacancy> vacancies) {
        this.vacancies = vacancies;
    }
...

}
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Person {

    @Size(min=3)
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]*")    
    private String name;

    @Size(min=3)
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]*")
    private String surname;

    private Integer id;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, String surname) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column (name = "id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    //@NotEmpty
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "surname")
    //@NotEmpty
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj!=null && ((Person)obj).getId() == id ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Integer id = getId();
        return id != null ? id.intValue() : super.hashCode();
    }




}
```

Event:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event")
@XmlRootElement
public class Event {
    private Integer id;

    @Size(min=3 )
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]*")    
    private String name;

    @Size(min=5)
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z]*")    
    private String description;

    private Date date;

    @Future
    private Date eventDate;

    private User author;

    private Set<Candidate> candidates;
    private Set<Vacancy> vacancies;

    private EventType eventType;
    private EventStatus eventStatus;

    public Event() {
        super();
    }



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name ="id")
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj!=null && ((Event)obj).getId() == id ){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        Integer id = getId();
        return id != null ? id.intValue() : super.hashCode();
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Candidate> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }

    public void setCandidates(Set<Candidate> candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Vacancy> getVacancies() {
        return vacancies;
    }

    public void setVacancies(Set<Vacancy> vacancies) {
        this.vacancies = vacancies;
    }
}
```

In my @Controller class I write so method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateEvent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateEvent(Model model,
            @Valid @ModelAttribute("existedEvent") Event event,
            BindingResult result,
            @ModelAttribute("linkedCandidates") Set<Candidate> candidates,
            @ModelAttribute("linkedvacancies") Set<Vacancy> vacancies) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute("idEvent", event.getId());
            return "eventDetails";
        }
        if (vacancies != null) {
            for (Vacancy vacancy : vacancies) {
                vacancy.getEvents().add(event);
            }
        }
        if (candidates != null) {
            for (Candidate candidate : candidates) {
                candidate.getEvents().add(event);
            }
        }
        event.setVacancies(vacancies);//place ONE (if comment this line - will //work)
        event.setCandidates(candidates);
        eventService.update(event);//error here
        return "redirect:goToEventMenu";

    }
```

update:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class EventService {
     public void update(Event event) {
        eventDao.update(event);
    }
....
}

@Repository("eventDaoImpl")
public class EventDaoImpl extends DaoAbstract implements EventDao {
    @Autowired
    CandidateDao candidateDao;

    @Autowired
    VacancyDao  vacancyDao;



    @Override
    public boolean update(Event event) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        if (event == null) {
            return false;
        }
        session.update(event);
        return true;
    }
...
}
```

Sorry for a lot of code/ But I don't know that write here)

**UPDATE 1**

stackTrace:

```
10.09.2013 11:46:14 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/ui] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.epam.hhsystem.model.vacancy.Vacancy#6]] with root cause
org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: [com.epam.hhsystem.model.vacancy.Vacancy#6]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:697)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:735)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:727)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$5.cascade(CascadingAction.java:258)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:388)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.cascadeOnUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:241)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultUpdateEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireUpdate(SessionImpl.java:786)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:778)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.update(SessionImpl.java:774)
    at com.epam.hhsystem.jpa.EventDaoImpl.update(EventDaoImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy38.update(Unknown Source)
    at com.epam.hhsystem.services.EventService.update(EventService.java:24)
    at com.epam.hhsystem.services.EventService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$3653e1b6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.epam.hhsystem.services.EventService$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$8266fd26.update(<generated>)
    at com.epam.hhsystem.web.controllers.EventMenuController.updateEvent(EventMenuController.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:838)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
I noticed, that I have no problem if I write change mapping Vacancy in Event:
@ManyToMany(/*cascade = CascadeType.ALL,*/ fetch = FetchType.EAGER)// I comment cascade
    public Set<Vacancy> getVacancies() {
        return vacancies;
    }
```

Why? for simmetrical entity Candidate this mapping works:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Candidate> getCandidates() {
        return candidates;
    }
```

If I delete relation between Event and Vacancy in initally code variant- it works good

If I delete relation between Event and Candidate in initally code variant- it DON'T works

Comment: Please post the complete Exception (Hibernate/Spring) will often have some usefull details in there Exception, that make finding the bug much more easier.

Answer (score 5):

This happens if you are tring to save Two objest with same Id in same session.

First of all this should not happen try to find out why it is happening and avoid it. If it turns out to be requirement of a use case then try

`session.merge`

Cheers !!

Comment: I want to find reason of arisen two objects

Comment: @user2740224 - I think you have already done enough research yourself, the problem is same event object is existing both in Candidate and Vacancy, that is why the options which are trying are working. Best would be to seperately save Candidate, Vacancy and Events.

Answer (score 0):

Try to merge the vacancies with the current transaction, before you use it.

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager entityManager;

...
 public String updateEvent(Model model,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("existedEvent") Event event,
        BindingResult result,
        @ModelAttribute("linkedCandidates") Set<Candidate> candidates,
        @ModelAttribute("linkedvacancies") Set<Vacancy> vacancies) {

    if (result.hasErrors())...

    ...
    List<Vacancie> mergedVacancies = new ArrayList<>();
        if (vacancies != null) {
        for(Vacancie v : vacancies) {
             mergedVacancies.add(entityManager.merge(v));
        }
    }


    for (Vacancy vacancy : mergedVacancies ) {
         vacancy.getEvents().add(event);
    }
    ...
    //Attention: mergedVacancies is not null like in the original code
    event.setVacancies(mergedVacancies );
    ...
 }
```